# What is the #MileHighOps?

Tags: discussion, twitter, milehighops

From what I know, something across the pond (for me) [is being turned off](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/609053383832535041), and there is [a lot of hard drives](https://twitter.com/shanemadden/status/608740836826677248) - <s>27</s> 36 in the image:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

What's happening, and will it affect my obsessive use of Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What's happening,

Our Oregon data center is being moved to Denver (the mile high city).

> and will it affect my obsessive use of Stack Exchange?

It shouldn't. If it does, something went wrong.

Also - 9 * 4 == 36 (not 27) ;)

Comment: There is 4. Failed my [#edexcell](https://twitter.com/hashtag/EdexcelMaths?src=hash) maths then...

Comment: /picard ***THERE ARE FOUR DRIVES!***

Comment: I assume we get videos when the data center is on the lorry and being towed across states to Denver?

Comment: @rene http://c8.alamy.com/comp/B09A1F/m25-motorway-daf-lorry-with-wide-load-prefabricated-mobile-home-B09A1F.jpg

Comment: Lol spinning platters. Isn't that quaint! Y'all can't afford SSDs? Do you have a paypal account?  I'd be glad to donate a couple bucks if SE is hard up :(

Comment: Oy. Spinning rust has its uses, I'll let you know, @Won't - not everything needs to be on SSDs...

Comment: ... Yes it does.  *Yes everything DOES need to be on SSDs.* Take it back.  **Take.  It.  Back.**

Comment: hopefully we can get a blog post out about this. Lots of cool time laps video to share.